# How do I make a div tappable but make the anchor links take precedence/cancel the div tap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-safari, addeventlistener

Web development isn't my strongest point, so apologies if this is foolish, but I want to have a div that is tappable on mobile so I can intercept the tap and do things.

I'm attaching a `touchdown` event listener to the div in JavaScript, and when I tap, I color the div to indicate it's been selected.

However, if there's an anchor tag `<a href="..."></a>` within the div with some text in it (totally valid in this case), I don't want the div to be highlighted when you're just clicking the link.

I'm not sure the term in web development, but is there a way to make the anchor tag intercept touches so they don't get sent to the div if the anchor tag is selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional in the event handler to test if the event target is an anchor.  I used the `click` event in my example, but it should work with `touchdown` also.

```js
var tapDiv = document.querySelector('#tap');

tapDiv.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  //conditional ensures the clicked element isn't an <a>
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'a') {
    e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
  }
});
```

```css
#tap {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: black;
}

#tap a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="tap"><a href="#">This is the anchor</a></div>
```